# Autorotation in iOS 6.1 for custom camera view

Tags: ios, objective-c, ipad, camera, ios6.1

I've read almost every post around here regarding my problem but none of the solutions seems to work on my app.

So, I use a custom camera view (with buttons on toolbar and an overlay) that is being presented modally from a view controller. My app only supports landscape left and right for the orientation. And i want to stop the camera view from autorotating when it's being presented. I've put all the methods needed for autorotation on my view controller and my app delegate. I've checked on my plist file too and the supported rotations are correct. But my camera view keeps on rotating to any rotation (portrait and landscape) when I rotate the device, resulting on the overlay and the toolbar being incorrectly positioned. I also can't check on the camera view's orientation because i tried putting NSLog on shouldAutoRotate method, but it doesn't get called at all.

So how can I check the rotation on my custom camera view? And how can I force it to not rotate and stay still?

If my code is needed, I'll post it here. If anyone can help me on it I'll greatly appreciate it because it frustrates me so much right now.

Thank you. Cheers.

Comment: Your project having navigation controller?

Comment: Yes, I use a navigation controller

Comment: Okay, I think for now the only workaround I can do is to lock the autorotation using the button on the iPad itself.

Comment: what is your iOS target version?

Comment: Perhaps you need more control. Try the AVCam sample from Apple: http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#samplecode/AVCam/Introduction/Intro.html%23//apple_ref/doc/uid/DTS40010112

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create a new class of "UIImagePickerController" and implement the rotation delegates in the .m file as given,

```
// For lower iOS versions
- (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)toInterfaceOrientation  {

return ((toInterfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeLeft) || ((toInterfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeRight)));
}

// For iOS version 6.0 and above
- (BOOL)shouldAutorotate {

return YES;
}


- (NSUInteger)supportedInterfaceOrientations {

return (UIInterfaceOrientationMaskLandscape);
}
```

And make an instance of lets say MyImagePickerController instead of UIImagePickerController, and present it. This will work :)

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I'm trying this out now and I'll let you know if it works :)

Comment: Man, thank you very much. It works well. Accepted your answer already. :)

Answer (score 0):

Create a category for **UINavigationController**

```
@interface UINavigationController(autoRotation)

-(BOOL)shouldAutoRotate;

@end

@implementation UINavigationController

-(BOOL)shouldAutoRotate{

  return [[self.viewControllers lastobject] shouldAutoRoatate];

}

-(NSUInteger)supportedInterfaceOrientations {

  return [[self.viewControllers lastobject] supportedInterfaceOrientations];

}

@end
```

Implement these two methods in your corresponding view controllers
and return the orientation what u exactly want....

Comment: Thank you for answering. But I've also tried this method already. Didn't give me the result that I wanted. But maybe I was missing something. So, maybe I'll try tinkering more with this method.

Comment: How do you bring your cameraview? using presentModalViewController? If yes your UIImagePickerViewController does't exist in your navigation stack. So you have to create a category for your IMagePickerViewController and call shouldAutoRotae...

Comment: Yes, I am using presentModalViewController. Can you give me the example code to create the category? I'll definitely try it out cuz it seems like it is the way.

Answer (score 0):

xcode -> file -> new file select cocotouch in the leftpane select objective-c category ->next
select give name **Picker** category on **UIImageImagePickerController** from dropdown

## import

@interface UIImagePickerController (picker)

-(BOOL)shouldAutoRotate;
-(NSUInteger)supportedInterfaceOrientations;

@end

## import "UIImagePickerController+picker.h"

@implementation UIImagePickerController (picker)

-(BOOL)shouldAutoRotate{

```
    return yourOrientation;
```

}

-(NSUInteger)supportedInterfaceOrientations {

```
    return yourInteger;
```

}

@end

After this when your device's orientation changed then the method shouldAutoRotate get called from your UINavigationController category at this time you have to find out if cameraview is presented if yes then you have to call shouldAutoRotate of Picker

See the following code

in your view controller's shouldAutoRotate

-(BOOL)shouldAutoRotate{

```
   if([self presentingViewController])// Camera is present 
         return [instanceOfUIImagePickerController shouldAutoRotate];
   return yourOrientaionNeededForThisVC;
```

}